# Extending the derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

A linear functional $\mu: C^1(\mathbb{R^n})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which follows the Leibniz rule $\mu(fg)=\mu(f)g(0)+\mu(g)f(0)$ is called a derivative at $0$.

It is easy to show that such a derivative is in fact the partial derivative along the vector $\sum_i \mu(f_i) e_i$, where $f_i$ are the projection maps, and $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors.

My question is: can we talk of the derivative on larger spaces? Say, on $C(\mathbb{R^n})$, for instance. 
Does there exist some non-zero derivative on $C(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

And, given a partial derivative along some vector $v$, can we extend the operator $\frac{\delta}{\delta v}$ to $C(\mathbb{R})$ such that it still obeys the Leibniz rule?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch3.pdf

This text goes over weak derivatives, which is a generalization of the derivative.

You can also defined distributional derivatives on the space of distributions (dual space to the space of compactly supported smooth functions.)